# What does midbar mean?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

Midbar is commonly translated as desert or wilderness. It seems to come from the root davar (word) so I'm guessing the idea is that a midbar is a place where survival is most evidently dependent on the word of Hashem. Is this right?

I've found sources on line that say that the Sahara is the third biggest desert in the world with the Arctic as the second biggest and Antarctica as the biggest. I have no doubt that the Sahara qualifies as a midbar. My question is does the Arctic and Antarctica qualify as a midbar in loshon kodesh? They certainly seem to be places where survival is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Yonathan Sacks z"l explained once that the meaning behind the word "midbar" is to mean [(COVENANT & CONVERSATION
The Wilderness and the Word, Bamidbar 5768)](https://www.rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation/bamidbar/the-wilderness-and-the-word/):

> The Hebrew word midbar, wilderness, has the same root as the word dabar/davar, meaning “word” or “thing.” It has the same letters as medabber, “speaking.” It is in the wilderness that the Israelites hear revelation, the word or speaking of G-d

There's a famous Midrash (see for example [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_DeRabbi_Yishmael.20.2.4)) that explains why the Torah has been given in the midbar. Why was the Torah not given in the Holy Land, Eretz Yisrael?  The answer lies, tells the Midrash, in the fact that a midbar has no ownership on itself. A midbar belongs to no one. So too, everyone has an equal claim to the Torah (see also Midrash Tanchuma, Chukas 21:1)

[Elsewhere](https://www.rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation/bamidbar/wilderness-and-revelation/), Rabbi Sacks explains the deeper meaning behind the reason why the Torah was given in the midbar:

> The giving of the Torah in the wilderness is an essential feature of Jewish history. Had the Israelites received the Torah in the land, it would be indissolubly associated with the land. Exile would mean the end of the covenant. It would make no more sense to keep Torah while in exile than to obey the laws of Russia while living in Spain.

What made the G-d of Israel different was the fact that He was sovereign of the universe, not a local deity. That is why the Jewish people survived dispersion. Only the G-d of everywhere can be found and worshipped anywhere.

I would strongly recommend this article, to further grasp the essence of the word "midbar" and the relationship between the giving of the Torah and us being in exile.

https://www.rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation/bamidbar/wilderness-and-revelation/

Answer (score 1):

The noun **Midbar** is best translated as *wilderness*, not necessarily *desert*.

The distinction being that a wilderness is a place devoid of human habitation and settlements.

The term *desert*, although coincidentally usually not conducive to human settlement, is only about a lack of precipitation, rainfall or snowfall. And to emphasize, it doesn’t necessarily imply a lack of availability of water. A desert can be filled with wellsprings, underground aquifers or like the continent of Antarctica can be covered with ice and snow because whatever precipitation has ever fallen there over the millennia has not evaporated because of the extreme and continuous cold.

So returning to the subject of wilderness being devoid of human settlement, the Torah, in its categorization of different types of creations, has four general categories of: inanimate objects דומם (things which are silent and do not have their own power of locomotion), plants צומח (things which sprout, usually, but not limited to *sprouting from* the ground), animals חיות (meaning things which do not sprout and which possess the power of self-locomotion. They may also be able to make noises and even possess some form of communication other than speech.) and humanoids מדבר (beings which have the power of speech, either oral or written or both).

And this underlines the association of wilderness מדבר (pronounced Midbar) and humanoid מדבר (pronounced M’Daber, meaning speak or speech) settlement. That a wilderness can be profusely filled with all kinds of life, but is devoid of speech.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I'm understanding you correctly Antarctica does not qualify as a midbar because the limited presence of human settlement there disqualifies it?

Comment: @JamesRead On the contrary, according to World Population Review: "Antarctica is last on the population list, as there are no permanent residents there. However, up to 4,400 researchers and personnel live there in the summer and 1,100 are there in the winter." Although only the 5th largest continent in regard to land mass, in terms of even temporary human residents, it is the least occupied by humans and therefore would definitely be considered a wilderness (Midbar).